# Making a heap with list causes errors

Tags: c++, heap, containers

The following code:

```
std::list<int> list;
std::make_heap(list.begin(), list.end());
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f847aaadaef13fd)

causes a whole bunch of errors, including:

> error: no match for 'operator-'

When I declare `list` as `std::vector`, I do not get these errors, why?

Comment: Why don't you include the error messages?

Comment: I've edited the question to include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), a live demo and an example of error. If you feel like this edit does not properly reflect your problem, feel free to rollback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two iterators passed as first and second arguments to the function `std::make_heap` has to be `RandomAccessIterator`s. List iterators are not `RandomAccessIterator`s while `std::vector` and `std::array`'s are.

In the standard this is specified in the interface for `make_heap` at §25.1:

```
template<class RandomAccessIterator>
  void make_heap(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last);
template<class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
  void make_heap(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
                 Compare comp);
```

and in §25.1.5.5 we have that:

> If an algorithm’s template parameter is named RandomAccessIterator, RandomAccessIterator1, or RandomAccessIterator2, the template argument shall satisfy the requirements of a random-access iterator

And finally, random access iterators are described in §24.2.7:

> A class or pointer type X satisfies the requirements of a random access iterator if, in addition to satisfying the requirements for bidirectional iterators, the following expressions are valid as shown in Table 111.

[image: table for the requirements of random access iterators]

Comment: Thanks for the very insightful answer!